# Android things: using commands writeBuffer, write, byte[] to write many bytes in i2c registers

Tags: java, android, kotlin, iot, android-things

I'm developing an application to move dc motors, using android things.

At this stage I already know which commands I have to process, but I do not know how. ([Using the i2c smartdrive sensor with a Pio Cli commands to run motors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368262/using-the-i2c-smartdrive-sensor-with-a-pio-cli-commands-to-run-motors))

***Below example i2c from guide google developers:***

```
public void writeBuffer (I2cDevice device, byte [] buffer) throws IOException {
     int count = device.write (buffer, buffer.length);
     Log.d (TAG, "Wrote" + count + "bytes over I2C.");
}
```

***My question (based on the code above) is:***

1) How to write (in Kotlin) pio i2c I2C1 0x1B write-raw 0x46 128 0x05 0x00 0xD1 in buffer to pass as parameter in writeBuffer function?

e.g.: var buffer = (new byte[] (byte) 0x46, 128, 0x05, 0x00, 0xD1, value.i2cValue.toByteArray()), did not work.

My final project is based on the project below:
https://github.com/Nilhcem/i2cfun-androidthings/tree/arduino_slave/app/src/main/java/com/nilhcem/androidthings/i2cfun

***quote:*** I know that I2C1 and 0x1B are not required because they are passed parameters, either before, or in I2cDevice.

Comment: `var buffer = (new byte[]...` is not quite Kotlin

Comment: Not really an answer, but there are very simple dc motor controllers (such as L298N) that work using 4 GPIO pins and there's plenty of examples online and even some drivers.

Comment: Hi, tks, but I stay working with two car windshield motors/rpi3/smartdrive-i2c-driver. Bridge H L298N  not support the amperage of the motors and my power supply switched of the 12v and 20A

Comment: I solved this issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i_selEXwqWM5tQN7KPcqWd35Di_avNTa/view?usp=sharing but now I have issue with PeripheralManager in Preview 7 A Things: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3IQmnIQ7BodDonbIeVVXyjlAF3tOYnH/view?usp=sharing  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1htJCNt--1iJtrIMkVLgT3XIETUjKQU_1/view?usp=sharing  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141634/peripheralmanagerservice-throws-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: @NEUBERSOUSA If you've solved the issue, please post how you solved it. If you have any other questions. Please create a new question.

Comment: I solved:         val buffer = byteArrayOf(0x46, 128.toByte(), 0x05, 0x00, 0xD1.toByte())  and                                                                       
device?.write(buffer, buffer.size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved: val buffer = byteArrayOf(0x46, 128.toByte(), 0x05, 0x00, 0xD1.toByte()) and device?.write(buffer, buffer.size)